Cant initialize Sentry in PHP
I have some basic trouble with calling Sentry in PHP (non-framework).
Docs.
I installed Sentry with composer. But if I try to call it after autoloader I get an error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Sentry\init().

My code looks like:
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

\Sentry\init([
    'dns' => 'example_public_key'
]);

I also tried to call Sentry\init but with the same result.
I hope I have some simple misunderstanding about how to call a library installed by composer. Could someone help me with it? Thank you.

Some more details are required for debugging. Please show the command you used to composer require and the part of the composer.json.

FYI: How do I format my posts?

What PHP version are you using?
